# Use apply to extract parenthesis content from dataframes

Tags: r, regex, apply

I want to extract only the content inside the parenthesis, this works pretty well if I use vectors (example below):

```
j<-"[8] Q(+.98)"
gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(j, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", j))[[1]])
```

Now I want to to use apply to run the above code in multiple columns in a dataframe. Below is what I have done which does not work.

```
a<-c("[7] C(+57.02)",  "[11] C(+57.02)",  NA, NA)
b<- c("[16] C(+57.02)",   NA, NA,NA)
c<-c("[9] Q(+.98)" ,   "[13] Q(+.98)" , "[14] C(+57.02)",NA)
abc<-as.data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))

abc_in<-apply(abc, 2, function(x) 
  gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", x))[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does what you tell him, that is to take only the first element of the regmatches list for each column. I advise to use `str_extract` from stringr package, that gives a vector as a result and is easier to write and use:

```
library(stringr)
abs_in <- apply(abc,2,function(x){ gsub("[\\(\\)]", "",str_extract(x,"\\(.*?\\)"))})
> abs_in
     V1       V2       V3       V4
[1,] "+57.02" "+57.02" NA       NA
[2,] "+57.02" NA       NA       NA
[3,] "+.98"   "+.98"   "+57.02" NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `apply()` or any packages.  Since we're operating on the entire data frame, we can first coerce it to a matrix then just use `sub()`.

```
sub(".*\\((.+)\\).*", "\\1", as.matrix(abc))
#   V1       V2       V3       V4
# a "+57.02" "+57.02" NA       NA
# b "+57.02" NA       NA       NA
# c "+.98"   "+.98"   "+57.02" NA
```

That gives you a matrix back.  If you need to retain the data frame structure, then

```
abc[] <- sub(".*\\((.+)\\).*", "\\1", as.matrix(abc))
```

Of course, you could loop the data frame columns.  But for that I would go with `lapply()` over `apply()` since a data frame is a list.

```
abc[] <- lapply(abc, sub, pattern = ".*\\((.+)\\).*", replacement = "\\1")
```

Coercion is done implicitly by `sub()`, so starting with factors is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`, additionally, you need to specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when binding the dataframe:

```
abc<-as.data.frame(rbind(a,b,c), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(stringr)
regex <- "\\(([^()]+)\\)"
str_match_all(abc, regex)
```

This yields

```
[[1]]
     [,1]       [,2]    
[1,] "(+57.02)" "+57.02"
[2,] "(+57.02)" "+57.02"
[3,] "(+.98)"   "+.98"  

[[2]]
     [,1]       [,2]    
[1,] "(+57.02)" "+57.02"
[2,] "(+.98)"   "+.98"  

[[3]]
     [,1]       [,2]    
[1,] "(+57.02)" "+57.02"

[[4]]
     [,1]           [,2]        
[1,] "(NA, NA, NA)" "NA, NA, NA"
```

Just always take the second group.